# MongoDB Array Query - Single out an array element

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I am having trouble with querying a MongoDB collection with an array inside.
Here is the structure of my collection that I am querying. This is one record:

```json
{
"_id": "abc123def4567890",
"profile_id": "abc123def4567890",
"image_count": 2,
"images": [
  {
    "image_id": "ABC123456789",
    "image_url": "images/something.jpg",
    "geo_loc": "-0.1234,11.234567890",
    "title": "A Title",
    "shot_time": "01:23:33",
    "shot_date": "11/22/2222",
    "shot_type": "scenery",
    "conditions": "cloudy",
    "iso": 16,
    "f": 2.4,
    "ss": "1/545",
    "focal": 6.0,
    "equipment": "",
    "instructions": "",
    "upload_date": 1234567890,
    "update_date": 1234567890
  },
  {
    "image_id": "ABC123456789",
    "image_url": "images/something.jpg",
    "geo_loc": "-0.1234,11.234567890",
    "title": "A Title",
    "shot_time": "01:23:33",
    "shot_date": "11/22/2222",
    "shot_type": "portrait",
    "conditions": "cloudy",
    "iso": "16",
    "f": "2.4",
    "ss": "1/545",
    "focal": "6.0",
    "equipment": "",
    "instructions": "",
    "upload_date": 1234567890,
    "update_date": 1234567890
  }
]
}
```

Forgive the formatting, I didn't know how else to show this.

As you can see, it's a profile with a series of images within an array called 'images' and there are 2 images. Each of the 'images' array items contain an object of attributes for the image (url, title, type, etc).

All I want to do is to return the object element whose attributes match certain criteria:

**Select object from images which has shot_type = "scenery"**

I tried to make it as simple as possible so i started with:

```
find( { "images.shot_type": "scenery" } )
```

This returns the entire record and both the images within. So I tried projection but I could not isolate the single object within the array (in this case object at position 0) and return it.

I think the answer lies with projection but I am unsure.

I have gone through the MongoDB documents for hours now and can't find inspiration. I have read about $elemMatch, $, and the other array operators, nothing seems to allow you to single out an array item based on data within. I have been through this page too https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/  Still can't work it out.

1. Can anyone provide help?
2. Have I made an error by using '$push' to populate my images field (making it an array) instead of using '$set' which would have made it into an embedded document? Would this have made a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    "result": {
      $filter: {
        input: "$images",
        as: "img",
        cond: {
          $eq: [
            "$$img.shot_type",
            "scenery"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

#### [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/stjUIImDgBr)

Comment: Thank you for this. I need to learn more about aggregation. I thought I could do this query with a simple 'find'. I was wrong.

Comment: You're welcome. There are free courses by mongo db. Take at least one of those @Phfog. Takes 1 or 2 days. Learn to use `$match` and `$project` and `$unwind` it's almost enough

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$elemMatch` in this way (simplified query):

```js
db.collection.find({
  "profile_id": "1",
},
{
  "images": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "shot_type": 1
    }
  }
})
```

You can use two objects into `find` query. The first will filter all document and will only get those whose `profile_id` is 1. You can omit this stage and use only `{ }` if you wnat to search into the entire collection.
Then, the other object uses `$elemMatch` to get only the element whose `shot_type` is 1.

Check an example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HocrcIiT5ql)